# Google Chrome does not understand top:50% unlike other browsers

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari

Seems Google Chrome 36 is broken and does not understand `top:50%` in my example.

IE 11, Opera 12.17 and Firefox 31 work just fine. Chrome and Safari are broken (and I guess other WebKit/KHTML browsers are broken too).

```
<div class="box_outer">
    <div class="box_inner">
        <div class="box">
                <h1>Hello</h1>   
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<style>
.box_outer {
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.box_inner {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: relative;
}
.box {
    position: absolute;
    left: -220px;
    width: 400px;
    top: -220px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: red;
}
</style>
```

I know I can do the following:

```
.box_outer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;  
}
```

But this is not a solution to the problem just a different approach.

How can I fix it for Chrome with minimal changes?

[You can test it on JSBIN here](http://jsbin.com/xilavode/1/edit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here's the fix. For me it seems like a bug in Webkit browsers.

```
.box_outer {
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.box_inner {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute; /* INSTEAD OF relative */
}
.box {
    position: absolute;
    left: -220px;
    width: 400px;
    top: -220px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not clear what you are trying to do here, but the result that you are getting in other browsers can be achieved in crome using:

```
.box_inner {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've just posted similar fix to that problem. It is weird why any position except relative works. They all should work (and they do in other browsers).